# JQuery mobile pageslide, new facebook menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

Here my story:

I want something like the new facebook menu on the left side of the screen. It's really nice and I hope to add this to my webapp, but the problem is, I am really not good in css and even worse in css3.

After few hours searching I found out this link:

https://github.com/perezd/jquery-pageslide

It is exactly what i want, it's perfect. But it doesn't work (not yet) for mobile. When the link is pressed, it opens a whole new page, instead of the div sliding into the view.

Any ideas how to get this working?

Comment: what have you tried? Example code would be nice as well, please edit your question and/or add a link using http://www.jsfiddle.net to help us better understand where you are stuck in the process

Comment: Okay, sorry I will do that tomorrow. I did use the code from the github link in my post. I did refer to the mobile jqeury files (css and js) and did bind the pageslide to a button. When i press it, it opens a whole new page. While I am writing this comment, I am thinking, maybe it is because jquery mobile adds to the div "data-role="page" automatically? Well that's just a thought, but i will check it tomorrow :) I hope I gave you an answer ;) if not tell pls.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I also wanted to implement this new FaceBook style menu and [this is what I came up with](http://blog.aldomatic.com/facebook-style-slide-out-menu-in-jquery-mobile//). Hope it helps. I am sure this could be done better but this was my attempt.

Answer (score 3):

This topic is old but here is a working solution for mobile devices :

it's working on Windows phone, iOs and Android Devices.

I've tried to keep the code as simple as possible, it's easy to understand and modifiy.

http://apptitudes.github.com/SlidingMenuJS/

Check the file menu_nav.js it's less than 100 lines.

Answer (score 1):

Not fully working but should point you in the right direction:

- http://jsfiddle.net/LwrqY/5/
- http://jsfiddle.net/LwrqY/5/embedded/result/ (for mobile testing)

The slide pages don't load the text but the slide transition works, Also you might have to tweak the close transition as well.

Hope this help