# Jquery-mobile: page layout with fixed left hand menu

Tags: jquery-mobile, css-position, navbar

I would like to make a jquery-mobile app having a left hand menu.

Is there a way to have it **fixed** like the fixed NavBar can be set? I think I need a vertical NavBar on the left side.

Thank you, F.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put the css "position:fixed" into the containing div of the list view, this produces a fixed effect.

Comment: probably yes, but what about Page transitions? Moving from one page to another the left hand list we be replaced/reloaded... NavBar instead can avoid reloading as I would... Thanks

Comment: the solution is add the element outside the JQM Page and set it fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Related:

- [JQuery mobile pageslide, new facebook menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794689/jquery-mobile-pageslide-new-facebook-menu/7795644#7795644)

Examples:

- http://jsfiddle.net/LwrqY/5/
- http://jsfiddle.net/LwrqY/5/embedded/result/ (view on mobile)

Now these are just examples and will need to be tweaked to work, just a concept