# CSS animated menu like facebook IOS app

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div with "display:none" taking up 25% of the page. When a button on the page is clicked the div becomes visible and shows a menu to the user. I want to animate the div to appear as if the page is sliding to the right and the menu is behind it, like the menu on the facebook IOS app can this be done with css and javascript?

Comment: Like this? click on the bars http://m.zachrip.net/p/

Comment: yes like that but only move it about a quarter of the way across the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753024/how-to-make-a-sliding-menu-similar-to-the-facebook-mobile-side-menu-with-html-cs) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794689/jquery-mobile-pageslide-new-facebook-menu) [these](http://lab.hakim.se/meny/) [pages](https://github.com/i8ramin/fb-menu), haven't tried them though.

Comment: Mind telling me which one?

Comment: The second link you gave "of". I looked at that and it had a good solution

Answer (score 0):

Best to do this is with CSS3 & Javascript. I force hardware acceleration for the animation making it smooth on mobile. Check this plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/GGQLn519tPCrqjwHER4W?p=preview

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.